# Pass class as constructor's argument

Tags: actionscript-3, class, constructor, arguments

I'm trying to pass my object class as constructor argument. I have something like this:

```js
package myclass {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

public class Example extends MovieClip {

    public var  _stageImg:Bitmap;
    public var  _stageData:BitmapData;
    public var  _stageClass:Class;

    private var _stage:Object;

    public function Example(stageClass:Class) {
        _stageClass = stageClass;

    }

    public function createStage():Object {
        _stageData      = new _stageClass(0,0);
        _stageImg       = new Bitmap(_stageData);
        _stage          = addChild(_stageImg);

        return _stage;
    }

}
}
```

Now, when I try to create my Example:

```
    import myclass.Example;
    var example:Example = new Example(myObjClass);
```

I get message, that I'm not passing any variable (Error #1063). Why is that? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Where do you define myObjClass?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an instance of your class instead of the definition of the class itself.

In ActionScript it's a bit clunky, but you can get the class definition of an instance like this:

```
//first get the fully qualified classname, i.e. including the package
var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(myObjInstance);
//then get the class definition for that name
var Klass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
//and finally pass it to your constructor
var example:Example = new Example(Klass);
```

(note: I named the variable 'Klass' because 'Class' is a reserved keyword)